# Find the largest cylinder inscribed inside a sphere. Is this calculation correct so far?

Tags: calculus, optimization

> A right circular cylinder is inscribed in a sphere of radius $r$. Find the largest possible volume of such a cylinder.

I have that the radius of the cylinder is $r$, the radius of the sphere is $R$, and the height of the inscribed cylinder is $h$. So
$$(2r)^2+h^2=(2R)^2$$
$$4r^2 + h^2 = 4R^2$$
$$h=2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$$
So volume of the cylinder is:
$$V=2\pi r^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$$
$$V'=4\pi r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}+2\pi r^2\frac d{dr}\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$$
And I think:
$$\frac d{dr}\sqrt{R^2-r^2}=\frac r{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}$$
so
$$V'=4\pi r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}+\frac{2\pi r^3}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}$$
$$=4\pi r(R^2-r^2)+2\pi r^3$$
$$4\pi rR^2-4\pi r^3+2\pi r^3=4\pi rR^2-2\pi r^3$$
So finding critical values:
$$4\pi r R^2-2\pi r^3=0$$
$$4\pi r R^2=2\pi r^3$$
$$4\pi R^2=2\pi r^2$$
$$\frac{4\pi R^2}{2\pi}=r^2$$
$$r=\sqrt2R$$
Someone else who is better at math is getting $r=\sqrt{\frac23}R$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dr}\sqrt{R^2-r^2}=\frac{\color{red}{-}r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}$

Comment: You're missing some parentheses in the very first displayed equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a sign error in computing the derivative of $\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$.
$$\frac d{dr}\sqrt{R^2-r^2}=\frac{-r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}$$
Thus
$$V'=4\pi r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}-\frac{2\pi r^3}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}=0$$
$$4\pi r(R^2-r^2)-2\pi r^3=0$$
$$2(R^2-r^2)=r^2$$
$$2R^2=3r^2$$
$$r=\sqrt{\frac23}R$$

Answer (score 2):

You might enjoy the fact that you actually do not need derivatives. By the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

$$V^2=16\pi^2\cdot \frac{r^2}{2}\cdot \frac{r^2}{2}\cdot(R^2-r^2)\leq 16\pi^2\left(\frac{R^2}{3}\right)^3 $$
i.e. $V\leq \frac{4\pi R^3}{3\sqrt{3}}$, with equality attained at $\frac{r^2}{2}=R^2-r^2$, i.e. at $r=R\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Comment: Does he actually know the AM/GM inequality?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I believe AM-GM *should* be taught long before derivatives, but that is just my personal opinion. If the OP does not know it, this might be a good moment to learn it.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks!